# Unable to run any lighthouse reports on two domains - Lighthouse returned error: Something went wrong

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, lighthouse

I am getting this error report every time I try to run a URL from two specific domains in both pagespeed insights and dev tools. No details or code given - Lighthouse returned error: Something went wrong.

This started last week. I can run AMP specific URLs but error each time on standard site. Makes me think there is a javascript issue or something blocking the tool from completing.

Comment: What are the domains that fail? Does the devtools console show anything related to lighthouse?

Comment: crosswalk.com and biblestudytools.com. I was able to run lighthouse in devtools but there is no data for FID.

Comment: also will not run on https://www.thinkwithgoogle.com/feature/testmysite/

Comment: In Lighthouse, try toggling the Clear storage checkmark and running again, it used to be a big problem in older versions of Chrome and other Chromium-based browsers. I didn't have any trouble with it.

Comment: Hmm, that's really strange. The testmysite page says that Lighthouse returned error but I was able to run Lighthouse with no problem on Chrome and Edge...I truly have no idea what the problem might be anymore.